# Hypothesis testing - Thesis

Tags: hypothesis-testing, interaction, medicine

I am doing a thesis project in which I need to answer three hypothesis, one measures the direct effect of  health consciousness (high vs. low level) on healthy grocery shopping behaviour (high vs. low). Which test should I use for this hypothesis?

My other two hypothesis include a moderator. One measures the level of Covid-19 Anxiety (high vs low) on health consciousness and healthy grocery shopping behaviour.
And the other measures shopping channel (online vs. offline) on health consciousness and healthy grocery shopping behaviour. Should I use PROCESS for these two hypothesis?

I have a total of 200 respondents and they are all from The Netherlands with a mean age of 33.58

Below my hypothesis:

H1: There is a positive relationship between health consciousness and healthy grocery shopping behaviour.

H2: The positive relationship between health consciousness and healthy grocery shopping behaviour is moderated by COVID-19 anxiety, such that this relationship is stronger for higher values of COVID-19 anxiety

H3: The positive relationship between health consciousness and healthy grocery shopping behaviour is moderated by shopping channel, such that this relationship is stronger for online grocery shopping

Comment: -You are dichotomizing several variables -- taking a continuous (I think) variable and turning into a binary. This throws away lots of information, so makes any statistical testing way less useful (less powerful). Can you analyze the actual data without dividing into high vs. low?

Comment: Please improve the title. "Thesis" is the context of your work, but is not part of the title. The title should state the statistical question you are trying to answer.

Answer (score 0):

The test depends on serval parameters (e.g. random sample, data) and statistical assumptions, see e.g. this [paper](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3116565/).

Considering your hints I would start with a logit regression, assuming that your `Y` is dichotomous (0/1). see e.g. this [website](https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/r/dae/logit-regression/) if you use r.